# How can I fill a textfield pressing one button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a several forms with lots of textfields, and my goal is that the user can save and retrieve their work in progress in wordpress. But I am pretty lost right now, and I thought that a simple first step to start would be changing an string empty value to a different value contained in a button, and I would be grateful if some of you guys could give me some ideas.
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty variable or better use `TextEditingController` and button onPressed use `controller.text ="someText";`, make sure to call `setState` in this case. But if you wish to save even after page changes, use `state-management` to store data or to restore data even after app quit, use localStorage like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to handle it.

More [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html).